# Share Genymotion's Network with its host

Tags: networking, android-emulator, vpn

Due to my peculiar circumstances in Iran with very restricted Internet access, I manage to find a way to connect to real Internet on my Android phone.

Now I want to run the solution on a Genymotion's instance and share the VPN-ed Network within Genymotion to the host and then share the host with my home network.

I know how to do the latter part, but I want to know is there anyway to share the internet (VPN Connection) within Genymotion via an interface to the host (Linux).

I do not mind if there is another emulator that fits better for my problem (the more lightweight the better, but also simple enough for me to be able to configure it). Furthermore, I'd appreciate your suggestions.